# App crashes while reading files from Storage path in noughat

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file, android-7.0-nougat, android-storage

### Issue:

The code is for choosing a file from external storage for doing OTA 
        update from Android App.This works well in Kitkat but when it comes to 
        Nougat phones(Moto G4) while choosing the Path App is crashing.

I tried debugging, the issue is with this line                                    `file = new File(item.getFilePath());` this creates `NullPointerException` in Nougat version,I also tried giving permission in Manifest for Reading External Storage,but still issue persists.what could  be the issue? I have posted the code below.Please help

```
 public class ChooseImageFileDialog extends Activity {


       private FileListAdapter mAdaptor;
       private ArrayList<FileFolderItem> mFileFolderList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mChooseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_button);
        mChooseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSelectedFile != null) {
                getIntent().putExtra(RETURN_PATH_RESULT, 
                    mSelectedFile.getPath());

                setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

        mFileFolderList = new ArrayList<FileFolderItem>();
        mAdaptor = new FileListAdapter(this, mFileFolderList);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View view, int 
        position, long id) {
            FileFolderItem item = mFileFolderList.get(position);
            if (item == null)
                return;

            File file = new File(item.getFilePath());

            highlightSelectedItem(listview, view);
             }
        });
```

**Modification** :27/11/2017

```
      mChooseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSelectedFile != null) {
                 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkPermission()) {
                        Log.e("value", "Permission already Granted, Now you 
                     can save image.");
                     }
                    else {
                        requestPermission();
                    }
                }else {
                    Log.e("value", "Not required for requesting runtime 
                    permission");
                    getIntent().putExtra(RETURN_PATH_RESULT, 
                    mSelectedFile.getPath());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
                    finish();
                }

            }
        }
    });


     private boolean checkPermission() {

       int result = 
             ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ChooseImageFileDialog.this, 
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
         if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             return true;
         }else{
             return false;
       }
    }


    private void requestPermission()
    {

       if(ActivityCompat.
          shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ChooseImageFileDialog.th
              is,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) 
          {
          Toast.makeText(ChooseImageFileDialog.this, "Write External Storage 
          permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this 
          permission in App Setting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } 
          else 
          {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ChooseImageFileDialog.this, new 
          String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 
                                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
          }

    }
```

---

I have modified the code to get runtime permissions also but still 
   Application is crashing.Still having the same problem

Comment: You should check runtime permission starting from Android 5.1. Did you check/enable runtime permission?

Comment: no i just tried static permissions only..i will try..

Comment: I put my answer below :)

Comment: yes yes ..i saw..thanks..

Comment: i anyone have sample codes  for giving runtime storage  permission please post..

Comment: `file = new File(item.getFilePath()); this creates  NullPointerException`. As item in not null (see statement above it) i cannot believe that you would have a null pointer exception here. Impossible.

Comment: item.getFilePath() ;is giving null in Nougat..rest for all version it is giving some file path

Comment: i have posted a modified code also please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

You must request permission in Runtime for devices above Android 5.1.

So you need to ask for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission :)

Read the following documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: He need to ask for permission above android 6.0.

Comment: for runtime permission the Target SDK should be 23 ryt? in my case min Target SDk is 18 so  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() will not work

Comment: you can use your own context,   context.checkSelfPermission

Comment: `above Android 5.1. = android 6.0 , right ? `. No. 5.2 would already be above. You make it very confusing and not to the point talking in this way.

Comment: @diegoveloper didn't get you?Please explain more!